# Error $parse:syntax token '' is unexpected - Space in String

Tags: angularjs, syntax

My code was working well until I use string with a space between two words.
I am using AngularJs.

```
stringAmi = '<i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-2x" ng-click="demandeAmiNotif(' + $scope.invite + ');"></i>';
```

$scope.invite is the string where I keep a name of a user like : "Victor Hugo"
I have this error :

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Hugo' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 22 of the expression [demandeAmi(Victor Hugo);] starting at [Hugo);].
```

Comment: You still have to generate valid JS.

Comment: So the resulting line of code being executed is `demandeAmiNotif(Victor Hugo);`  Yup, that's a syntax error alright.

Comment: But it's working with demandeAmiNotif(Victor); I mean when $scope.invite="Victor";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have much nesting strings on your template and  things are becoming complex. However, in this case, is missing escape the function call argument because it is inside a string and not being passed as an argument, but as a string.

```
var stringAmi = 
    '<i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-2x" ng-click="demandeAmiNotif(' 
    + '\'' + $scope.invite + '\''
    + ');"></i>';
```

But seriously though, it looks as terrible as it is, I don't know why you have to do this in such way, but consider using a different approach, a solid way easier to maintain.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.invite = 'Vitor Hugo';
        $scope.demandeAmiNotif = function(name) {
            console.log(name);
        };
        $scope.stringAmi =
            '<button ng-click="demandeAmiNotif(' + '\'' + $scope.invite + '\'' + ');">Click this!</button>';
    })
    .directive('bindHtmlCompile', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function() {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
                }, function(value) {
    
                    element.html(value && value.toString());
     
                    var compileScope = scope;
                    if (attrs.bindHtmlScope) {
                        compileScope = scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlScope);
                    }
                    $compile(element.contents())(compileScope);
                });
            }
        };
    });

angular.element(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div bind-html-compile="stringAmi"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I am using Cordova, google maps and angularJs this is why it looks terrible, I have an other error now : Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: demandeAmiNotif(

Comment: @DionysoSong alright, if you have the opportunity, try a simple solution. About the new error, sorry about that, actually you have to escape apostrophes instead of quotes. I've updated my answer.